# PHP Mail Setting

Tags: php

i just start working as a flash web designer. right now i make a 1 flash website.

i make this website in flash & to upload the web content i use a HTML file. and i also create a CONTACT US page in this site.  now i have to send a email. for that i use a php coding. But when when i click on send button then i got a error. My error is

```
".$mess[1]."   ".$mess[0]."
"; } next($post_vars); } mail($_REQUEST['recipient'], $subject, "
".$message." " , $headers); echo ("Your message was successfully sent!"); ?> //
```

in this page i use this code.. code is

```
<?
Error_Reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

 while ($request = current($_REQUEST)) {
    if (key($_REQUEST)!='recipient') {
        $pre_array=split ("&777&",  $request);
        $post_vars[key($_REQUEST)][0]=$pre_array[0];
        $post_vars[key($_REQUEST)][1]=$pre_array[1];
    }
    next($_REQUEST);
}



reset($post_vars);


$subject="From ".$post_vars['your_name'][0] ;
$headers= "From: ".$post_vars['your_email'][0] ."\n";
 $headers.='Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';
 $message='';
  while ($mess = current($post_vars)) {
    if ((key($post_vars)!="i") && (key($post_vars)!="\your_email") && (key($post_vars)!="your_name")) {

        $message.="<strong>".$mess[1]."</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$mess[0]."<br>";
    }
    next($post_vars);
 }

mail($_REQUEST['recipient'], $subject,  "
<html>
<head>
 <title>Contact letter</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
  ".$message."
</body>
</html>" , $headers);
echo ("Your message was successfully sent!");

?>
<script>
    resizeTo(300, 300);
</script>
```

.................................................

Please help me to solve this error....

Please Reply.....

Answer (score 0):

Your error doesn't make sense, that's just some code.

Your form is also vulnerable to e-mail header injection.
W3Schools has a [better code sample](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_secure_mail.asp) for a contact form.

Try avoid using `$_REQUEST` for things like sending e-mail.
You would think that a form has to be submitted in order to send a mail.
But with `$_REQUEST`, you can also open the page directly, as in `domail.php?your_name=somename&your_email=someone@example.com`